# Is delta method better than bootstrap to generate standard error for marginal effects?

Tags: bayesian, bootstrap, delta-method, robust-standard-error, marginal-effect

I read [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3837/85404343b97b62e780109cb321b52a945cc2.pdf), [here](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~ckirby/brad/papers/2011BayesianInference.pdf), [here](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~ckirby/brad/papers/2011BootstrapMCMC.pdf), [here](https://math.mit.edu/~dav/05.dir/class25-slides-all.pdf), and [elsewhere](https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article/20/2/255/1003275) that "

- Parametric bootstrap closely related to objective Bayes. (That’s why
  it’s a good importance sampling choice.)
- When it applies, parboot approach has both computational and
  interpretational advantages over    MCMC/Gibbs. (...)
- (...) the use of parametric bootstrap sampling to carry out Bayesian
  inference calculations. (...) possible in a subset of those
  problems amenable to MCMC analysis, but when feasible the bootstrap
  approach offers both computational and theoretical advantages."

On the other hand, the [delta method](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modmarg/vignettes/delta-method.html) is widely used to estimate [standard error (SE) for marginal effects (ME)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122066/how-to-use-delta-method-for-standard-errors-of-marginal-effects?rq=1) as in the example below taken from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376682/is-there-any-better-alternative-to-linear-probability-model):

```
set.seed(12345)
n <- 20000
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n))
dat$y <- ((2 + 2 * dat$x + + rlogis(n)) > 0) + 0
library(margins)
fit.logit <- glm(y ~ x, binomial, dat)
summary(margins(fit.logit, variables = "x"))
```

**My questions are:**

1) Are the SE from the `delta method` more "robust" than those that would be obtained via the `parboot approach`?

2) If not, how would the `parboot approach` be implemented to estimate SE for ME in R?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Delta method is a first order Taylor series approximation that relies on normality assumptions. Bootstrap is less restrictive in that regard so should be preferable. With your actual example and not this contrived one, fit your model and use something like the syntax below for bootstrapping: `summary(margins(fit.logit, vce = "bootstrap", iterations = 5000))`. `margins` offers bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you very much @HeteroskedasticJim. I ran the code using the sample above but I get an error. I wanted to know if this is because of this example being contrived? Here is the error: `Error in [[<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "z", value = c(Var_dydx_x = NA_real_, : replacement has 5000 rows, data has 1`

Comment: I noted not to use the contrived example. One, it's 20k cases so takes too long. Two, it fails for some reason with one predictor.

Comment: Now used this example `x <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp * wt, data = mtcars) summary(margins(x, variables = "hp", vce = "bootstrap", iterations = 20000))` from cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/…. But the error is the same: `Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "z", value = c(Var_dydx_hp = NA_real_,  : 
  replacement has 20000 rows, data has 1`. **Any thoughts?**

Comment: Do not specify any variable to pull out. Just get everything and interpret the choice effects. The package manual is a good reference for working examples. Though I must admit that the package has some strange behaviours.

Comment: That works. Thank you very much. Just one more questions: what type of bootstrap if this? Would it be possible to do the `parboot approach`?

Comment: Again, check the manual. The package author is @Thomas on this site, they would know. You would probably have to code parametric bootstrap yourself as I doubt that is parametric bootstrap.